# Efficient Websocket Data Handling

Tags: java, javascript, json, websocket, packet

I'm creating an online game using HTML5. I was going to communicate data over Websockets using JSON strings, so a typical string will have the action that was invoked and the data to go along with it:

```
{action: "chat", user: <cookie>, message: "Hello, Java!"}
```

Server-side, the JSON string would be parsed, and then go through a Case statement, which would send the data to the method which matches the action specified:

```
switch (message.action) {
    case "chat":
        // send message
        break;
}
```

The thing is, there will be about 20-30 actions once I'm done, and a Case/Switch statement seems really inefficient and messy in this respect. Is there a more efficient way to handle client-server communication through WebSockets? Someone suggested constructing TCP packets, and sending those. I have no idea how to do that in JavaScript.

Comment: What is the server side environment?

Comment: HashMap with the action as the key and a Runnable instance as the value? Then its a one-time init and from that moment on just a single lookup. Suggesting that makes my hairs stand up a little, but the other thing that pops into my head is 'reflection' and that I really would use as a last resort.

Comment: Its a Play Framework Java backend

Comment: why dont you create different endpoints or "methods" (im not really familiar with websocket...) for different actions?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the Switch/Case statement I mentioned in my post?

Answer (score 1):

There are two patterns that will help you here.

The **first** is the [Publisher/Subscriber pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern). This will allow you define subscribers for specific events.

The **second** one, is the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This pattern will give you a way of structuring message handlers without falling in big if-else cascades or large switch-case statements.

You can create objects that subscribe to a particular subset of events. Inside those subscribers, you can create strategies for handling each particular event.

This solution is scalable and maintainable, you can add new subscribers and new strategies to each subscriber without big modifications. Also, strategies and subscribers can be unitary tested.

For example, you can have game events related with the game play, and chat events. In your server side you would create an publisher object, that gets events from the websocket connection, and then you would create a subscriber than handles the chat events, and a subscriber that handles the actual game play events. Inside of the chat subscriber, you would create different strategies for handling messages like 'chat.start', 'chat.message', 'chat.close', etc... You could add later on a strategy for a new event type, or a subscriber for a new feature easily.

Answer (score 1):

I also would think about just sticking to the standard and using urls...

**index.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var walve = require('walve');

var server = new http.Server(function(req, res) {
  // send your front end html
}).listen(3000);

require('./action1')(server);
require('./action2')(server);
```

**action1.js**

```
module.exports = function(server) {

    var action1 = new walve.Server({
      url: '/action1'
    });

    action1.on('connect', function(wsocket) {

      // handle wsocket stream

    });

    action1.listen(server);

};
```

**action2.js**

```
module.exports = function(server) {

    var action2 = new walve.Server({
      url: '/action1'
    });

    action2.on('connect', function(wsocket) {

      // handle wsocket stream

    });

    action2.listen(server);

};
```

A complete example how this is done with a WebSocket forwarding images and one forwarding messages can be seen [here](https://github.com/bodokaiser/messenger).

This allows you to have the single actions goodly separated to add server side logic. However this may not make sense if you are only forwarding web socket data to all clients. In this case just built some event handler on top:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');

ws.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var message = JSON.stringify(e.data);

  emitter.emit(message.name, message.body);
});
```

Comment: I must admit I'm not very familiar with Node.JS

Comment: No problem - we all are starting somewhere :)